# Issue "Calling" a .csv file when writing a batch file

Tags: excel, csv, smtp, gmail, blat

So... here's my issue. Forgive me, I am pretty inexperienced in coding but im trying to get something to work for my company.

We are looking for some way to notify users of email outage when gmail goes down, so i found a program "Blat" which does this though our SMTP server.

I have looked through their support documents and google, but cant seem to find a how to on this. The best way (That i know of?) to run blat, is by creating a .bat file with the executions it needs to make. For the -to function (The to: section in the email) i want to have it call an excel or csv  document with the phone numbers in it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not sending out individual emails but but a slew of the addresses in the BCC field.  you can just load in the addresses with a ";" as the delimiter and send.